# Android findFragmentById returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, findviewbyid

I have an activity that manages a list of fragments. One of these is a ListFragment, and when the activity tries to find it during Create() I get a Null exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.foodexp01b.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:154)
```

The ListFragment is not yet created, but I need to have it into the fragment array as the others. What should I do?

Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[LOGIN] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.loginFragment);
        fragments[HOME] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.homeFragment);
        fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.settingsFragment);
        fragments[SETTINGS].getView().findViewById(R.id.back_button1)
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                currentFragment = HOME;
                showFragment(HOME, false);
            }
        });
        fragments[DESTINATIONS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.destinationFragment);
        fragments[DESTINATIONS].getView().findViewById(R.id.back_button2)
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                currentFragment = HOME;
                showFragment(HOME, false);
            }
        });
        fragments[MAP] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        fragments[RESTAURANT] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.restaurantFragment);
        fragments[RESTAURANT].getView().findViewById(R.id.restaurant_back_button)
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                currentFragment = MAP;
                showFragment(MAP, false);
            }
        });
        fragments[FAVORITES].getView().findViewById(R.id.favoritesFragment);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

the ListFragment code

```
public class FavoritesFragment extends ListFragment{

    private ListView listView;
    private List<BaseListElement> listElements;

    OnFavoritesFragmentListener mCallback;

    ArrayList<String> favorites;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnFavoritesFragmentListener {
        public void onSearchSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnFavoritesFragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFavoritesFragmentListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        favorites = new ArrayList<String>();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, favorites));
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

EDIT

The activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.foodexp01b.HomeFragment"
          android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.foodexp01b.LoginFragment"
          android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.foodexp01b.SettingsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.foodexp01b.DestinationFragment"
          android:id="@+id/destinationFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.example.foodexp01b.RestaurantFragment"
          android:id="@+id/restaurantFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.foodexp01b.FavoritesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/favoritesFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which line of code is `MainActivity.java:154`?

Comment: `fragments[FAVORITES].getView().findViewById(R.id.favoritesFragment);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `fragments[FAVORITES] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.favoritesFragment)`

Comment: I know, but it is declared in the activity xml. How can I get it?

Comment: Why don't you insert the line @tony indicated prior to performing `fragments[FAVORITES].getView()`.  `fragments[FAVORITES]` is null until you initialize it.

Comment: uh sorry @tony !!! now I got, I was absolutely sure that I had wrote that... But now I have this exception `Caused by: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment FavoritesFragment{415dc380 #6 id=0x7f05002b} did not call through to super.onActivityCreated()`

Comment: Yes! just added the super method onActivityCreated. Thanks a lot guys! @HeatfanJohn